# Setting row class for sap.m.Table rows

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to assign a class to a row in my `sap.m.Table` dynamically using my view model `SearchResults`.

Unfortunately it's ignoring my class properties (see below).

How do I do this in my XML view ?

```
<ColumnListItem class="{SearchResults>typeClass}">
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply CSS properties to row, you will also need take predefined CSS class of table `.sapMListTbl` along with your custom CSS class like I have done [here](http://jsbin.com/pizoma/edit?html,css,output).

I would suggest you to use formatter to apply these classes along with class from your model.

Comment: can you give me an example of the formatter, to be clear I only want to apply the class to certain rows (from the model) but ColumnListItem class="{SearchResults>typeClass}" doesn't pickup the value of typeClass.

Comment: As pointed out by @cschuff attributes are not bindable.
You can try trick given by him, however if it doesn't work; you can do it from controller([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pizoma/edit?html,css,output)) if you are ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the class attribute is not bindable since it is not a property.

As a workaround you could do sth. like this:

```
<ColumnListItem visible="{
  path: 'SearchResults>typeClass',
  formatter: 'my.formatter.formatClass'
}" />

my.formatter.formatClass = function(typeClass) {
  // in a static formatter this refers to the control, here your ColumnListItem
  this.addStyleClass(typeClass);
  // just always return true for the visible property
  return true;
}
```

Note: The formatter can't be a member of your controller since then you won't be able to refer to the control (this will be the controller itself). Hence the formatter needs to be a static function.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!!!!

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2016/05/17/coloring-table-rows-conditionally-in-sap-ui5-xml-views-based-on-odata-service

Hopefully this help anyone who's had the same problem...